# How to use crystal report user defined page size?

Tags: crystal-reports

I use

and set the page setup of .rpt
 - I checked the No printer option and Dissociate formatting page size
 - I chose User Defined Size in dropdown
 - I set Unit in pixel (Horizontal: 1200px, Vertical: 816px)

But the report viewer still still shows Letter size and the remaining Columns are not being Displayed ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Cross-Tab](http://www.urbainczyk.de/juri/crosstabs_in_crystal_reports.pdf) on crystal report so that the page width will automatically adjust depends on number of column.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

I suggest forcing via javascript the width of elements in your page.

A script like this should work (the name of the elements could change, inspect you HTML),

```
//execute when page is displayed on screen
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CrystalReportViewer1_toptoolbar").css("width", 1200); 
    $("#CrystalReportViewer1__UI").css("width",1200));
}
```

don't foget to add jquery

```
<asp:ScriptManager  ID="ScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" runat="server" AllowCustomErrorsRedirect="true">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
  </Scripts>
 </asp:ScriptManager>
```